# Why does this Java grid not function correctly?

Tags: java, video, grid, game-engine

I am trying to make a grid (with minimal code) that blocks can snap to. What I want is when the mouse is in the grid square, the block moves to that square. What I have written essentially says that if the X or Y are beyond the grid block times the size of the block, move to the next grid block. Currently, this code creates a 3x3 grid, though the code SHOULD generate infinite gridspaces. I cannot move the block outside of this 3x3 grid.

```
public class Player extends Entity {
public Player(double entSize, boolean collideA, boolean collideB, double x, double y) {
    super(entSize, collideA, collideB, x, y);
}
public void init() {
    Texture texFile = loadTexture("stone");
    texture(false, true);
    texFile.bind();
    render();
}
void input() {
    int gridPosX = 1;
    int gridPosY = 1;
        if(getX() > gridPosX*entSize) {
            gridPosX += 1;
        } if(getX() < gridPosX*entSize) {
            gridPosX -= 1;
        } if(getY() > gridPosY*entSize) {
            gridPosY += 1;
        } if(getY() < gridPosY*entSize) {
            gridPosY -= 1;
        }
        this.x = gridPosX*entSize;
        this.y = gridPosY*entSize;
}
```

}
The X and Y values are what define the blocks position and shape parameters.

Comment: Do you mean to be modifying gridPosX before you check the next condition? You may want to look into using else-if instead, I think.

Comment: I want to update gridPosX everytime the Mouse.getX() is greater than the current grid space's maximum X (gridSpace * entSize because these are squares).

Comment: This might depend on your implementation but since gridPosX and Y are always initialized at 1, they can only vary from 0 - 2, which could be causing your 3x3 problem.

Comment: I didn't know that... Why is that their range? More importantly, how do I increase that range?

Comment: I managed to make the gridsize infinite using for loops, but the block jumps by two spaces unless the cursor is EXACTLY on the x/y line of the next space.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using for loops for the positive grid increments!
NEW CODE:

```
public class Player extends Entity {
public Player(double entSize, boolean collideA, boolean collideB, double x, double y) {
    super(entSize, collideA, collideB, x, y);
}
public void init() {
    Texture texFile = loadTexture("stone");
    texture(false, true);
    texFile.bind();
    render();
}
void input() {
    int gridPosX = 0;
    int gridPosY = 0;
        for(gridPosX = 0; getX() > gridPosX*entSize; gridPosX++) {
            gridPosX += 0;
        } if(getX() < gridPosX*entSize) {
            gridPosX -= 1;
        } for(gridPosY = 0; getY() > gridPosY*entSize; gridPosY++) {
            gridPosY += 0;
        } if(getY() < gridPosY*entSize) {
            gridPosY -= 1;
        }
        this.x = gridPosX*entSize;
        this.y = gridPosY*entSize;
}
```

}